# Extract repeated URL parameter strings

Tags: google-sheets

I want to extract `c=; t=; s=` values to columns, in delimited string with commas in a Google sheet. The values could be repeated multiple times up to 10. 
`c=` are always only two capital letters.

For example:

```
A   examples
&t=clothes&t=bags&s=other&c=US&c=FR&c=GB
&c=NL
&t=glasses
&c=US&c=FR&c=GB&t=watches&t=necklaces&s=other&s=required

B column (c= strings)
   US, FR, GB
C column (t= strings)
   clothes,bags
D column (s= strings)
   other, required
```

Comment: @I'-'I i feels like it's not necessary here. The pattern here is always after "`c=`" to be extracted until "`&`"  What I would have liked here is for the user to provide his current efforts to solve this instead.

Comment: @I'-'I I do get your point and agree. I mean obviously, it will be only to our benefit, so I'm all for it, all I'm saying is I just don't feel like it's an absolute necessity here.

Comment: @l'-'l  I have provided more examples, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&c=",","),"((?:[A-Z]{2},?)+)")
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([^A-Z]*)([A-Z]{2})([^A-Z]*)","$2, "),".$",)
```

- [A-Z] Any 2 letter uppercase word
- [^A-Z] Not a 2 letter uppercase word

Comment: Thanks @l'-'l this works really well.

Comment: `=textjoin(",", true, split(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^A-Z]", "|"), "|"))`

Answer (score 3):

try,

```
=join(",", split(mid(A1, find("&c=", A1)+3, len(A1)), "&c="))
```

[image]

Comment: @jeeped thanks for the solution.I added a couple of more examples, the solution doesn't work when c= comes before the other tags. i.e  ?c=US&t=tags  Is there a work around for that?

Comment: That's actually an easy solution BUT a) The change in the inquiry renders this solution invalid and changes to a question that render previous responses invalid are to be discouraged b) The new sample data change the solution from one chain-of-thought to another. No 'quick modification' can be made to adjust this response to suit. c) With the added problems of the new sample data, you are going to have to decide whether you are looking for an [tag:excel] or a [tag:google-spreadsheet] solution.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your input, you may decide to follow the logic: *Take all letters in Upper Case and split them by a space*. The letter in UpperCase in the standard US/UK alphabet are 26 and are between 65 and 90 in the ASCII table.

Thus, looping from each value and checking whether it is between 65 and 90 would be ok:

```
Public Function GetUpperCase(inputVal As String) As String

    Dim resultVal As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(inputVal)
        If Asc(Mid(inputVal, i, 1)) >= 65 And Asc(Mid(inputVal, i, 1)) <= 90 Then
            resultVal = resultVal & Mid(inputVal, i, 1)
        Else
            resultVal = resultVal & " "
        End If
    Next i

    GetUpperCase = WorksheetFunction.Trim(resultVal)

End Function
```

At the end, `WorksheetFunction.Trim` is quite handy, because it removes the multiple spaces and it reduces them to a single one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Jeeped's solution, but in case you were looking for a VBA implementation.

```
Private Sub parse_c()
    Dim result As String
    Dim lr As Long

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    result = ""

    For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & lr)
        For i = 1 To Len(cell)
            If (Mid(cell, i, 2) = "c=") Then
                If (result = "") Then
                    result = Mid(cell, i + 2, 2)
                Else
                    result = result & ", " & Mid(cell, i + 2, 2)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        cell.Offset(0, 1) = result
        result = ""
    Next cell

End Sub
```

> Loops through all active cells in Column A and substracts all the countries with the desired delimiter.

tested: *(also with some trickery, such as `=cc=UK`)*

[image]